# How can I get year from date

Tags: c#, mongodb

I want to get year from date in `mongodb`.
This is my simple script :

```
DateTime sDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(new DateTime(2013, 1, 15, 00, 00, 00), DateTimeKind.Utc);
DateTime eDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(new DateTime(2014, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59), DateTimeKind.Utc);

string map = @ "function(){
                                emit (_id.OwnerId, _id.Date {
                                    Date: Value.Date.getYear(),
                                    PurchaseAmount: parseFloat(Value.PurchaseAmount),
                                    PurchaseReturnAmount: parseFloat(Value.PurchaseReturnAmount),
                                    TotalAmount: parseFloat(Value.TotalAmount)
                                });
                           }";
string reduce = @ "function (key, values) {
                        var outValue = {purchsaeAmount:0 , purchaseReturnAmount:0, totalAmount:0 }
                        values.forEach(function (value) {
                        outValue.PurchaseAmount +=parseFloat(value.PurchaseAmount);
                        outValue.PurchaseReturnAmount +=parseFloat(value.PurchaseReturnAmount);
                        outValue.TotalAmount +=parseFloat(value.TotalAmount);
                        });
                            return outValue;
                        }";
```

In map I want to get only year, how  can I get start year(2013) and end year(2014)?

Answer (score 3):

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getFullYear();
var next_year = d.getFullYear()+1
```

out:

```
2013 2014
```